# Need help on my first Pro React Native Project

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I am currently building a **react native app** for my family's company and I am terrified with the idea of releasing an amateur-built App that does not respect any guidelines.

The goal of the App is to let their customers log in, send orders, get updated on them, and report problems.

I chose to use **Firebase/Firestore** to manage the Authentication and store the data.

The App is almost ready, everything functions as it should.

**My main concerns are my approach to Firestore/Firebase in my project and the structure of my project.**

The way I made it work is to create a `firebase.js` file at the root of my project, containing the following:

```
// Importing the functions needed from the SDK
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

// App's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx"
};

// Initialize Firebase

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const auth = getAuth(app)
const db = getFirestore(app);

export {auth, db}
```

Then when I need to retrieve, send Data, I just use the db const.

I have seen documentations about generating credentials for iOS and Android which would make more sense but I don't really know what to do.

Here is my project structure:

```
/.expo
/.expo-shared
/.vscode
/app
  /screens
    LoginScreen.js
    ForgotPasswordScreen.js
    HomeScreen.js
    OrdersScreen.js
    ReportsScreen.js
    ProfileScreen.js
    NewOrderScreen.js
    NewReportScreen.js
    NewAddressScreen.js
  /assets
    /images
      logo.png
/navigation
  tabs.js
/node_modules
.gitignore
App.js
app.json
babel.config.js
firebase.js
package-lock.json
package.json
```

The question is:

**What steps do you think I should take to have a proper commercial App, ready to be uploaded to the App Store?**

My question is broad, I'm looking for any advice to better my project.

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the structure of your project, I just want to point out that you're currently using firebase web SDK, which is fine. However, it's limited.

With the web SDK, you won't be able to use other firebase functionalities such as notifications, analytics, dynamic links, and more.

The preferred library for mobile react-native apps is @react-native-firebase.

according to the docs:

> React Native Firebase is a light-weight javascript layer connecting you to the native Firebase SDKs for both iOS and Android which aimes to mirror the offical Firebase Web SDK as closely as possible.
>
> Although the official Firebase JS SDK will work with React Native; it
> is mainly built for the web and has a limited feature-set compared to native.

Integration docs: https://rnfirebase.io/

After integration, your firebase.js config file would like this:

```
import auth from "@react-native-firebase/auth";
import firestore from "@react-native-firebase/firestore";

const db = firestore;

export { auth, db };
```